# Batch - Remove backups a week old

Tags: batch-file, backup

So I've got a batch file that backs up a folder to my Google Drive directory, like so:

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe a -r "D:\Google Drive\Saves Backup\%DATE%.rar" "D:\Documents\My Games\"
```

This makes a file called 30-Sep-12.rar (being run today) in the appropriate folder.

However, my question is this: Is there some way to go through said folder (D:\Google Drive\Saves Backup) and delete backups that are more than a week old, as determined by the filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why must you use the date embedded within the file name? The last modified date should be the same as the date embedded in the file name as long as the backup has not been modified since it was created.

FORFILES is one of the few Windows utilities that conveniently works with date arithmetic. Type `FORFILES /?` from the command line to get help on its usage.

```
forfiles /p "D:\Google Drive\Saves Backup" /m "*.rar" /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

If you have a risk that someone could modify a backup, thus changing the last modified date, then the above will not work. Parsing and comparing dates is a pain in batch. You would be better off using VBScript.

Comment: I'll have to check that out. Depending on what Google Drive does to the timestamps, or if the archive gets its timestamp changed if I were to extract it, I may have to go another route. Ideally if forfiles doesn't work for me I'll just write a PHP script to do what I want to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Worked for me but I had to remove the trailing \ from my `/p` argument for it to work